# Report viewer 2010 not displays all the rows from dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

HY
I have a reportviewer 2010 and I want to display some rows from my dataset.
In mydataset I have 5 rows, but after `reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);`
 I see in DataSource only 1 row which is displayed.

Has anyone some ideas why?

Below is my code, if you need more information please tell me.

```
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reportViewer.RefreshReport();
        reportViewer.Reset();
        reportViewer.Clear();
        ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", mydataSet);
        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I remade my rdlc file and it works fine now.
I supose something I did wrong first time my rdlc...